# OneNote on OneDrive: Sync error after name change

Tags: onedrive-for-business, onenote

User has a OneNote stored on his OneDrive for business and works in the OneNote Desktop app.
Now the user changed his name because of marriage. The synced notebook in OneNote App still points to the old name-URL and causes sync issues now.
Can I change it somehow in the settings?